# Want to add data-* attribute in a div which will be used by third party JS lib React Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
const speed :string =`{"speed": 0.2}`

<div className="section jarallax h-100vh"  data-jarallax={speed} 
    style={{backgroundImage: "url('/images/header-bg.jpg')"}} 
    id="home">
</div>

<Script src="./js/parallax.js"  strategy="beforeInteractive" />
```

It throws an Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is thrown because there is a mismatch between the conponents that are affected by server-side rendering and the rest of your UI. what you could try is to remove the **beforeactive** attribute in the script tag.

If that doesn't help, please visit this link:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Comment: +1 It worked thanks for the help. Can you explain will the script be added after the page now and that's why there was an error of dehydration?

Comment: It removed the error but the script is still not functioning.

Comment: Is there any output to the chrome dev tools console?

Comment: __While rendering your application, there was a difference between the React tree that was pre-rendered (SSR/SSG) and the React tree that rendered during the first render in the Browser. The first render is called Hydration which is a feature of React.

This can cause the React tree to be out of sync with the DOM and result in unexpected content/attributes being present.__